# How to make a vector that stores different data types for every run of a program?

Tags: c++

I have a program that makes a random file that contains the number of items it has and random items of a specific data type for each file, for example, file named 'integers' is '5 3 7 10 232 2', the first number being the number of items following and then random integers. The file named 'strings' is '3 jawhdjwa kks owoiwow', and so on for char and double too.

I made implementations for sorting algorithms and want to input, in the same implementation, the files with different data types in the following way: './a.out < strings' or './a.out < integers'. The sorting algorithms are already prepared to handle different data types but reading the different inputs to store in a vector of different types is not working. I've read a lot about typenames but still can't manage to do this.

TL;DR I want to input a file with a non-descriptive name such as 'hey.random_file', knowing that the structure of the file is first the number of items and then the items of a still unknown data type, how can I test the data type (for string, int, double or char) and then proceed to make a vector of the tested data type in a way that doesn't require me to duplicate code

This is what the main function looks like, the heap_sort() functions is tested to work with string, char, double and int but I can't manage to read the input of different data types.

```
size_t n;

if(print_input)
    cout<<"Array size: ";

cin>>n;

vector<int> arr(n);

if(print_input)
    cout<<"Array elements: ";

for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin>>arr[i];

heap_sort(arr);

if(print_input)
    cout<<"Sorted array: ";

for(size_t  i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout<<arr[i]<<' ';
```

Comment: What about making your sorting algorithms templates as well? Can you show a code example of what you already have so far please.

Comment: How do you expect the program to know the type of the inputs that it is getting?

Comment: `std::vector<std::variant<std::string, int, char, whatever>>`

Comment: @KyleWillmon The name of the file indicates the types

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've included the main.

Comment: That is not how you use a vector. Have a look at `std::vector::push_back` and `std::vector::reserve`

Comment: @Ayxan not exactly, I want it to be general, as long as the data type in the file is all the same.

Comment: @RenatoBrittoAraujo *but I can't manage to read the input of different data types* -- You have the solution already.  Take that entire code you posted, and templatize it instead of hard-coding it to `int`.

Comment: What do you mean by general? How is the vector supposed to know the type?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie But I can't put 'template <typename T>' in main because the compiler does now allow it.

Comment: @RenatoBrittoAraujo `if (input_is_int) run_my_program<int>(params); else if (input_is_string) run_my_program<string>(params);`...etc.  If you were to write the string version of what you posted, what difference would there be?  There shouldn't be any difference except you would be using `string` instead of `int`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks Paul, I will try this.

Comment: But I don't know how to "detect" the input

Comment: You said the files are named by what they contain!? `if (std::string{ argv[1] } == "integers") { /* ... */ } else if (std::string{ argv[1] } == "strings") { /* ... */ } else if // ...`

Comment: But what if i wanted to input a file with a non-descriptive name such as 'hey.random_file', knowing that the structure of the file is first the number of items and then the items of a still unknown data type, how can I test the data type (for string, int, double or char) and then proceed to make a vector of the tested data type in a way that doesn't require me to duplicate code?

Comment: *how can I test the data type (for string, int, double or char)* – first try reading a double, if it fails, its not a `double` and not an `int`. If it's not a `double` or an `int`, read a `std::string`. If it's length is 1, it's a `char`. But it also could be a string of length 1. To know for sure you'd have to check if all strings in the file are of length 1. Do distinguish between  `double`s and `int`s ... if `value == static_cast<int>(value)` it could be an `int`. But again you'd have to check every value in the file to be sure.

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/By48qHk2E ...click on "Run"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write one function template that does all the work, also using function templates:

```
template<typename T>
vector<T> input(istream&);

template<typename T>
void output(const vector<T>&);

template<typename T>
void do_sort(istream& s)
{
    auto v = input(s);
    sort(v);
    output(v);
}
```

Then use an explicit instantiation at runtime:

```
int main()
{
    // ...
    ifstream is(filename);
    if (filename == ”integers”)
        do_sort<int>(is);
     else if (filename == “strings”)
        do_sort<string>(is);
    // ....
}
```